# Progress Bar for DataGridViewColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, progress-bar

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2) Mark Rideout, a Microsoft developer explains how to create a progress bar column in a DataGridView, and provides a "bare-bone" code for DataGridViewProgressColumn class. His instructions on how to use it for databound datagridviews are:

> [If you are databound, then you can just change the column type of an integer column that has 0 through 100 values.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2?#d990e44a-b933-44f9-b940-077ffb356050)

Some people, including myself do not understand what does it mean to "change the column type of an integer column that has 0 through 100 values" in the case with databound grid, and Mark seems to be too busy to answer. Does anyone know how it is done?

Here is a quick sample of my case:

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class Record
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Progress { get; set; } // This is the int 0-100 field which 
                                          // has data for a progress bar

        public Record()
        {
        }

        public Record(int id, string name, int progress)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Progress= progress;
        }
    }
}

namespace Sample
{
    public partial class SampleForm : Form
    {
        private BindingList<Record> records;

        public SampleForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public SampleForm(BindingList<Record> records)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.records = records;
        }

        private void SampleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = this.records;
        }
    }
}
```

At what point exactly should I change the "Progress" column type to DataGridViewProgressColumn, and how is that done?

Answer (score 8):

As I understand you need to bind such type of columns to the properties which have type `Int32` and can have values from 0 to 100 (as percentage).

**Data entry class:**

```
class Data
{
    public int Progress { get; set; }
}
```

**Binding of the data:**

```
var data = new List<Data>() { 
    new Data() { Progress = 50 },
    new Data() { Progress = 60 },
    new Data() { Progress = 30 },
    new Data() { Progress = 92 },
};

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

** This is how it looks: **

[image]

Class, described in the article should be added to the project a built before adding columns to GridView.

And don't forget that allowed values only from 0 to 100.

**Steps**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide an example which will work for the databound scenario listed above?

Comment: sure.. moment please... just checked :)

Comment: Samich, this sounds stupid, I know... but how does your Column1 know that its type should be DataGridViewProgressColumn?

Comment: You can select the type of column in *Edit Column* dialog. Couple sec please, I'll post an image

Comment: BTW, it's quiet buggy solution.. :) After adding such column you may have problems with forms designer.

Comment: But my columns are autogenerated, how do I get to that dialog? (thanks a lot for your help)

Comment: With auto-generated columns it will not work (or at lease I don't know how)

Comment: I think I figured it out! Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no such thing build-in as "DataGridViewProgressColumn".
But you can get the class for it from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2/sample-code-datagridview-progress-bar-column?forum=winformsdatacontrols or an updated version from https://github.com/jimradford/superputty/blob/master/SuperPutty/Gui/DataGridViewProgressColumn.cs

Answer (score 0):

I use VB.NET the [attached Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117021/How-to-Create-ProgressBar-Column-in-DataGridView) is in C# anyway, so its going to be easy for you to Understand. 
Once you include the two classes, just call the Namespace in you form, build your solution, then add a `datagridview` control and add a column of type `DataGridViewProgressColumn` to the control.
You can thus use the following code to populate the control.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(20)
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(20)
```

P.S My code sample is in VB but am sure you can figure out it's equivallent for C#

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, so maybe this will help someone...

```
progressBar1.Bounds = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(columnIndex, rowIndex, true);
```